# Object required error on Set session = Connection.Children(0)

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to start a SAP GUI script and to change some of the variables of the VBA code.

I get

> Runtime error '424' Object required

on `Set session = Connection.Children(0)`

```
Public Sub SimpleSAPExport()
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")  'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
Set session = Connection.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection

'  Start the transaction to view a table
session.StartTransaction "SE16"
end sub
```

Comment: After each "`set XXX =`" add: `if XXX is nothing then msgbox "the thing above is broken"`

Comment: runtime error '424'
Object required
and VBA highlights the below line
     Set session = Connection.Children(0)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error message because the object `Connection` doesn't exist, just change this object to the actual object `SAPCon` and execute your code. I was facing same issue and it was solved changing this object:

```
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI") 'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection
```

Best,

Edgar M.

Answer (score 0):

if still hang problems after advice by Edgar M ( correcting `connection` to `SAPCon` ),
try adding a little delay before Set session..
(or before which ever line where the hanging occurs)
.. so in this case SAPCon has enough time to complete (within the run environment) before code continuation (related to ever faster getting pc's?).
So like:

```
..
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
WScript.Sleep 200
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
```

After this, the random hangs seemed over.
Best, JanW